# Target name "zip" not getting executed while running build.xml using ant

Tags: java, ant

I am running below build.xml using ANT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<project name="EITaaS_Testing" default="runtests">
    <path id="compile.classpath">
        <fileset dir="TEST_LIB">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <path id="run.tests">
        <fileset dir="TEST_LIB">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="dist">
            <include name="*"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="dist" />
        <delete dir="build" />
        <delete dir="test-output" />
        <delete file="test-output.zip" />
        <delete dir="log" />        
    </target>
    <target name="init"  depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <mkdir dir="dist" />
        <mkdir dir="test-output" />
        <mkdir dir="log" />
    </target>



    <target name="compile" depends="init" >
        <javac destdir="build/classes" debug="true" srcdir="src">
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target name="build-jar" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="dist/test-jar.jar" basedir="build/classes">  
        </jar>
    </target>
    <target name="runtests" depends="build-jar" >
        <java classname="org.testng.TestNG">
            <arg value="src/PortalTestcases_testng.xml"/>
            <classpath refid="run.tests"/>
            </java>
    </target>

    <target name="zip">
             <echo>Creating zip file...</echo>
            <zip destfile="test-output.zip" basedir="test-output"/>
            <echo>Done!</echo>
         </target>


</project>
```

My requirement is to zip test-output folder which is created after successful run. When I execute command "ant zip' only its creating the zip file without any issue. But when I execute the build.xml as a whole either from eclipse or using ant -y build.xml then the zip file is not getting created. Somehow its ignoring the zip command. I tried by changing the sequence of zip in build.xml but still no luck.

Comment: Try adding a dependency to the zip target. For exaample: "<target name="zip" depends="runtests">"

Comment: Try the opposite: add dependency to zip target in the default target (which is runtests) : `<target name="runtests" depends="build-jar, zip">`